# I have a laptop with Xubunutu, want to reinstall Windows 8, but can't enter bios on reload

Tags: xubuntu, bios

So, it's a Asus laptop, which came with Windows 8.1 and instantly loads in to the OS, no ASUS splash screens or anything. Is there a way to boot in to Bios in Ubuntu?

I installed Xubuntu using the Windows function of reloading in to Bios, but can't since i formatted the drive.

Installing Windows because it was faster with it, than with Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS (or probably UEFI menu if it's an 8.1 system) is the first component of your computer to start, it bootstraps everything else. It will never be affected by an operating system install.

Please give us the model of the device, so we can find out what you have to press to make it boot into UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: How does Windows 8 do it? It specifically has a setting to reboot to change Uefi settings.

Comment: Windows 8 does it with software, which we can't do, because we are not software. It can also be done by pressing hardware buttons during boot, but to figure out which ones we **need the model of your device**.